# How to make wireless or bluetooth microphone work on raspberry 4

Tags: raspbian, bluetooth, pi-4, microphone

I'm running raspbian-buster on raspberry 4. I need to make  wireless or Bluetooth microphone work. It's a production base project.

I've tried with common headset which used for cellphones.But it's not stable and the microphone doesn't work.
is it my problem with installing and configuring drivers or should i buy a specific brand for making it work ?

Comment: To reefer to the latest version is not such a god idea since it will change! Change it to the version you have (iso date)!

Comment: @MatsK I modified the post

Comment: And Bluetooth is quite generic so there is no "drivers" needed for the Bluetooth communication, you just have to choose the right profile (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bluetooth_profiles). And the topic has been discussed here https://askubuntu.com/questions/889164/use-phone-as-microphone-in-linux

Comment: I already connected to headphone but microphone not working

Comment: Maybe i should downgrade to raspberry 3 and install windows 10 iot since windows 10 doen't support raspberry 4.

Comment: You need to provide more info about the issue. What exactly is "not stable" and "doesn't work"? Does your headset show up in BT menu? How do you test it?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I guess i should change the bluetooth headset because the headset microphone doen't work even in windows 10 mashine. Please tell me which brand works with raspberry.